# How to add SRW package to existing Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, plsql-package

I'm setting new oracle db and want to add SRW package which is used for oracle reports.How to add this package and where can I found the functions and procedures of this package? Or should I write PL/SQL codes myself ?
Edit:DB is used for ERP.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, you should install Reports as SRW built-in package is closely related to that product; that is, probably, the best option you might choose.

If you have a database to spare (as I can't guarantee that - if you follow what will be said next - you won't harm the database), find IAS installation which has Reports installed.

Navigate to its `reports\admin\sql` directory which contains several files, one of them being `srwAPIins.sql` which *should* install the SRW package (by calling other files located in that directory); it is editable, have a look at its contents.

Once again: don't do that if you don't know what *exactly* you are doing.